# Python itertools.groupby with dictionaries with multiple values

Tags: python, grouping, python-itertools, dictionary-comprehension, itertools-groupby

I am trying to use the Python itertools.groupby function to change this list:

```py
items = [
  {'price': 5.0, 'name': 'Strawberries'}, 
  {'price': 5.0, 'name': 'Strawberries'}, 
  {'price': 5.0, 'name': 'Strawberries'}, 
  {'price': 11.23, 'name': 'Coffee'}, 
  {'price': 11.23, 'name': 'Coffee'}, 
  {'price': 3.11, 'name': 'Green Tea'}
]
```

into this:

```py
{
  'Strawberries': {'price': 5.0, 'quantity': 3}, 
  'Coffee': {'price': 11.23, 'quantity': 2}, 
  'Green Tea': {'price': 3.11, 'quantity': 1}
}
```

I have tried both:

```py
grouped = { 
  name: {
    'price': list(article)[0]['price'], 
    'quantity': len(list(article))
  } for name, article in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x['name']) 
}
```

and:

```py
grouped = { 
  name: {
    'quantity': list(article), 
    'price': list(article)[0]['price']
  } for name, article in groupby(items, key=lambda x: x['name']) 
}
```

with the following results:

```py
{
  'Strawberries': {'price': 5.0, 'quantity': []}, 
  'Coffee': {'price': 11.23, 'quantity': []}, 
  'Green Tea': {'price': 3.11, 'quantity': []}
}
```

`IndexError: list index out of range`

I'm not sure why I am only able to access article for one of the values within the sub-dict I am trying to create.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Is it guaranteed that items of the same name appear uninterrupted in `items`? Otherwise you'd you have to sort the list first if you want to use `groupby`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a blank list or the index error is because your `article` object is an iterator, which is fully consumed on the first call to `list(article)`.

When you get the price first, the price is correct but the quantity is an empty list  because you already consumed `article`. By contrast, when you get the quantity first   then take the first item's price, the second call to `list(article)` produces an empty list, which you try to index but cannot because there are no items.

Here is a solution with `groupby` where you save the `list(article)` and use it for both the price and quantity.

```py
grouped = {}
for name, article in groupby(items, key=lambda itm: itm["name"]):
    products = list(article)
    grouped[name] = {
        "price": products[0]["price"],
        "quantity": len(products),
    }
```

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, this assumes your `items` list is in the order that you want it. Often you will want the iterable passed to `groupby()` to be sorted in a meaningful way. But perhaps you just want to group consecutive items together, even if the same item occurs later in your list.

Comment: Use with caution. This solution works purely by luck because the same names appear uninterrupted in `items`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the best use case for `groupby` in my opinion. It's easier to build a `(default)dict` with a loop over `items`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(lambda: {'price': None, 'quantity': 0})

for item in items:
    subdict = result[item['name']]
    subdict['quantity'] += 1
    subdict['price'] = item['price']
```

Output:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>,
            {'Strawberries': {'price': 5.0, 'quantity': 3},
             'Coffee': {'price': 11.23, 'quantity': 2},
             'Green Tea': {'price': 3.11, 'quantity': 1}})
```

(The price if overridden by the last seen price for an item. This is ok if you don't expect ambiguous prices across items with the same name.)

edit: without `defaultdict`

```
result = {}
for item in items:
    result.setdefault(item['name'], {'price': item['price'], 'quantity': 0})['quantity'] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative!